# webcam studio 13.04

Tags: 13.04, webcam

I need to stream with watermarks. People say I need to use webcam studio to do that

It installs but when I open it the only thing I have is "The module webcamstudio is not loaded.  Virtual webcam will not be available."

The guide on the app google page has nothing in "installation". I'm getting angry at this

Comment: Webcam Studio used to work pretty fine until Patrick Balleux dropped the project just leaving an older version for further development. I am affraid Webcam Studio won't be the same now that Karl Ellis is maintaining the project. Sorry for that but I think that you will be in the need to find another solution for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

you can find useful infos about using and installing WebcamStudio 0.64 at "WebcamStudio Reloaded" G+ Community:

https://plus.google.com/communities/110329269823088092206

Karl Ellis

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.